# What is the ActionScript 3.0 Code to Make a Simple Button?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

What is the actionscript 3.0 code to make a very simple button that brings the user to the next frame? If I remember correctly in ActionScript 2.0 it was:
instance_name.onPress = function(){
gotoAndStop(2)
}
Or something like that. However, this isn't the case for ActionScript 3.0. So could someone please let me know? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActionScript 3 uses an event based system, so to be notified when the user clicks a DisplayObject, you need to listen for the click [MouseEvent](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html).

```
myDisplayObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
  event.target.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the answers here have the corret function for the functionality, but have a consideration user experience too, you might want to assign these values:

```
myDisplayObject.buttonMode = true //use the "hand" cursor on mouseover
myDisplayObject.mouseChildren = false //stops the children of the button firing the event, helpful especially when having text lables etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function eventResponse(evt:MouseEvent):void {gotoAndStop(2);}

yourButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,eventResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

private var button:Sprite = new Sprite();

```
      public function ButtonInteractivity() 
        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
        addChild(button);
      }

      private function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
        your code!!
      }
```